# How to read cookies that is set by CAS server in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cas

I am doing a single singon feature. I have more than one application and need to provide SSO feature.
App1 - Java
App2 - .NET
CAS SERVER - JASIG

when i login to cas server, say htts://server.com:8443/cas/login it sets a cookie for successful login.

So when i access any of the .net page, say http://xxxxx.com/login, i need to see whether there is any cookie already set. If cookie is already set then i need to get the cookie and authenticate the user.

The problem that i am facing is, i am not able to get the cookie set by Java(CAS Server) in .NET.

CAS SEVER is https and my .net app is http. Could that be an issue?

PLease advice.

-
Nimi

Comment: Your urls make it look like they are not on the same domain, but cookies are segmented by domain.

Comment: Ok.. here is the correct url. cas server - https://nimi.server.com:8443/cas/login
web app - http://nimi.server.com:8081/login/login.aspx
cas server is in https but web app is in http
Please advice.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an article which clearly talks about [cas server in asp.net](http://techslate.net/cas-cookies-and-asp-net/) issue.